# Finding linearly dependent vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying the following question from a competitive exam :

I need to find all values of x such that the vectors (x,1,1,1), (1,x,1,1), (1,1,x,1), (1,1,1,x) are linearly dependent in $R^4$.

I can see at a glance that x can be 1. I am speculating that x can be only 1.But I'm not sure. I am trying to find all such x. I'm trying to use the definition that these four vectors are dependent so that one vector can be written as a linear combination of remaining 3 but it becomes too complicated. Any help is appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: Compute the determinant, and set it to 0, that's one way, if you covered those. Do Gaussian elimination otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a&1&1&1\\1&a&1&1\\1&1&a&1\\1&1&1&a\end{bmatrix} \quad \text{ and } \quad W=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
Then 
$$A=aI+W+W^2+W^3=q(W), $$
where $q(t)=a+t+t^2+t^3$.

Observe that the eigen values of $W$ are just $4^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity $\pm 1, \pm i$. Then eigen values of $A$ will be 
\begin{align*}
q(1) & = 3+a\\
q(-1) & =a-1\\
q(i) & =a-1\\
q(-i)& = a-1.
\end{align*}
For linear dependence, we need at least one eigen value of $A$ to be $0$. Thus $a=1,-3$ are the values for which the vectors will be linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

The determinant of the matrix is $x^4 - 6x^2 + 8x - 3 = (x-1)^3(x+3)$, as wolframalpha is kind enough to tell us. Try [this link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det%20%28%7Bx%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2Cx%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2Cx%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%2Cx%7D%29).